# useEffect infinite loops when added a Dependency

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern

I've been doing a MERN stack edit page and unfortunately I run into infinite loop when I am including "fields" into my useEffect dependency and works perfectly fine when I removed it, but

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fields'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.
```

shows when I remove it.

Heres my code:

```
 const EditFields = () => {
  const menu = useSelector((state) => state.menu.menu);
  const loading = useSelector((state) => state.loading.isLoading);
  const [fields, setFields] = useState({
    name: "",
    description: "",
    price: "",
 });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (menu) {
      setFields({
        ...fields,
        name: menu.name,
        description: menu.description,
        price: menu.price,
        dishImage: menu.dishImage,
        imgData: menu.dishImage,
      });
    }
  }, [menu,fields]);

  return (
    <>
      {!loading ? (
        <div className="add-menu">
          <p className="head">Add Menu</p>
          <form>
            <div className="add-fields">
              
              <div className="group-field">
                <label>*Menu Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="fileBtn"
                  placeholder="Menu Name"
                  value={fields.name}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    setFields({ ...fields, name: e.target.value })
                  }
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div className="group-field">
                <label>*Price</label>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  placeholder="Price"
                  value={fields.price}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    setFields({ ...fields, price: e.target.value })
                  }
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div className="group-field">
                <label>*Description</label>
                <textarea
                  cols="30"
                  rows="10"
                  placeholder="Menu Description"
                  value={fields.description}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    setFields({ ...fields, description: e.target.value })
                  }
                  required
                ></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
      )}
    </>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `useEffect` call every time when `fields` changed, but inside `useEffect` you change `fields`, therefore we get an endless loop.
You can pass the function to `setState` the first argument of which will be the current state value.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (menu) {
        setFields(prevFields => ({
            ...prevFields,
            name: menu.name,
            description: menu.description,
            price: menu.price,
            dishImage: menu.dishImage,
            imgData: menu.dishImage,
        }));
    }
}, [menu]);
```

Comment: ine 28:9:  Parsing error: Unexpected token
[0]
[0]   26 |     if (menu) {
[0]   27 |       setFields(prevFields => {
[0] > 28 |         ...prevFields,
[0]      |         ^
[0]   29 |         name: menu.name,
[0]   30 |         description: menu.description,
[0]   31 |         price: menu.price,